# I keep getting the error " ValueError: invalid column index 2 at row 1 with 2 columns" when trying to import a file using np.loadtext

Tags: python, file, import, valueerror

I keep getting the error " ValueError: invalid column index 2 at row 1 with 2 columns" when trying to import a file using np.loadtext.

[This is the file that I am trying to import, it goes on for several more rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdbAN.png)

This is the code that I'm currently using to try and import the file.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


evo0_8f = '/content/drive/MyDrive/HR-Diagram/evo_0.8.txt'
evo0_8 = np.loadtxt(evo0_8f, skiprows=2, usecols=(1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The columns are numbered from zero.  You need `usecols=(0,1)`.

Or, since there ARE only two columns, just skip that parameter altogether.